# how can i loop in row header for excel files using c# using oledb

Tags: c#

Please assist.I am reading excel files.I need to check column headers(customerReferenceNumber) that all cells contains are not empty and no duplicates.

```
string columHeader ="customerReferenceNumber":
 public bool check(string customerReferenceNumber)
        {
            string cnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\nyathis\Desktop\SBSA_TestData.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string sql = "Select distinct CustomerReferenceNumber From [Sheet1$] " ;



            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cnStr))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    //Columnheader ==CustomerReferenceNumber
                    if (dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.Equals(stdColumns[0]))
                    {
                       //How can I do Logic I need to check if rows in these columnHeader                   had duplicate and row is not blank!!!!!!!!!
                        if(dt.Rows is not emptyornull 


                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```